# Infrared-controlled helicopter and Tizen

Tags: tizen, infrared, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have a Samsung Gear 2 with Tizen and RC helicopter Syma S107.
Now, I am developing a HTML5 Tizen application for helicopter control and have the following documentation:

```
webapis.irled.send(
    "17000,2015,15,14,18,15",
    function()
    {
        // Success callback
    },
    function(e)
    {
        // Failure callback
    }
);
```

Thus, the data, which should be sent is given in "DOMString" and that's pretty unclear and embarassing. I have a documentation for this helicopter and know the length of logical zero and logical unit and delay between them. Does anybody know how to implement it using this protocol? What is the first sent data (beginning sequence) and\or terminal sequence? How to work with it? Which values to sent and how to set delays \ lengths \ frequency? I would appreciate if you give any information on helicopter control or Tizen infrared protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will be interested then the protocol seems to be working like it works right like the same protocol in Android.

The first number is frequency. The second one is a period in us (10^-6 seconds) for IR-blaster on. The following is for turning off etc.

For example, "17000,2015,15,14,18,15" means:
"Switch on and use 17 000 Hz frequency. Turn it on for 2015 us. Wait for 15 us. Turn it on for 14 us. Wait for 18 us. Turn it on for 15 us. Switch off."

All other rules of timing are set according to the protocol.
For example, our helicopted used the following protocol: 600 us - logical unit, 300 us - logical zero, 600 us - delay.
Then, if we send "38000, 600, 600, 600, 600, 300, 600, 600, 300" then the helicopter receives the following byte sequence "1101". Some of controllers also require some kind of "checksum" be in the end of the sequence. All you need is instruction to the device.

Thank you for help, anyway. If someone has any questions, feel free to ask or discuss.